# Why does adding the last element in loop to vector segfault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++20

I have the below code where I'm parsing stdin to objects stored in a vector. Works fine until it gets to `chain->jobs.push_back(job);` one of the iterations where it segfaults. I've deduced that it fails when it gets the chain for the second time from the map but just don't see why the second access causes issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Job
{
    Job(){};
    Job(const Job& job) 
        : job_id_(job.job_id_), runtime_sec_(job.runtime_sec_), next_job_id_(job.next_job_id_) {};
    Job(int job_id, int runtime_sec, int next_job_id)
        : job_id_(job_id), runtime_sec_(runtime_sec), next_job_id_(next_job_id) {};
    Job& operator=(const Job& job){
        job_id_ = job.job_id_;
        runtime_sec_ = job.runtime_sec_;
        next_job_id_ = job.next_job_id_;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Job(){};
    int job_id_;
    int runtime_sec_;
    int next_job_id_;
};

struct Chain
{
    std::vector<Job> jobs;
};

void parse_input(std::vector<Chain>& chains)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::map<int, Chain*> chain_map;
    
    Job job;
    std::regex job_regex("([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)");
    while (getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << '\n' << std::flush;
        std::smatch matches;
        if (std::regex_match(line, matches, job_regex))
        {
            int job_id = std::stoi(matches[1].str());
            auto res = chain_map.find(job_id);
    
            Chain* chain;
            if (res == chain_map.end())
            {
                chains.emplace_back();
                chain = &chains.back();
            } else
            {
                chain = res->second;
            }
            Job job(std::stoi(matches[1].str()), std::stoi(matches[2].str()), std::stoi(matches[3].str()));
            chain->jobs.push_back(job);
            // chain->jobs.emplace_back(std::stoi(matches[1].str()), std::stoi(matches[2].str()), std::stoi(matches[3].str()));
            //chain->jobs.push_back(Job(std::stoi(matches[1].str()), std::stoi(matches[2].str()), std::stoi(matches[3].str())));
            // auto job = chain->jobs.back();
            chain_map[job.next_job_id_] = chain;
        } else
        {
            std::cout << "Malformed input\n";
        }
        std::cout << chains.size() << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Chain> chains;
    parse_input(chains);
    return 0;
}
```

sample stdin

```
job_id,runtime,next_job_id
1,30,23
2,23,3
3,20,0
23,50,4
4,43,0
```

**EDIT:**
the stacktrace

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555e524 in std::construct_at<Job, Job const&> (__location=0x1e8e5f176c2a300c) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:97
97          { return ::new((void*)__location) _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000055555555e524 in std::construct_at<Job, Job const&> (
    __location=0x1e8e5f176c2a300c)
    at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:97
#1  0x000055555555e569 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Job> >::construct<Job, Job const&> (__a=..., __p=0x1e8e5f176c2a300c)
    at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:518
#2  0x000055555555cff8 in std::vector<Job, std::allocator<Job> >::push_back (
    this=0x5555555bd2a0, __x=...) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1192
#3  0x000055555555ad09 in parse_input (
    chains=std::vector of length 2, capacity 2 = {...}) at main.cpp:58
#4  0x000055555555aff8 in main () at main.cpp:85
```

Comment: OT: You don't need the `Job` copy-constructor or copy-assignment operator functions. The default ones created by the compiler will do what you already do.

Comment: As for the crash, have you tried to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to find out when and where in your code it happens? What are the values of all involved variables at the time of the crash?

Comment: Don’t need the destructor either.

Comment: In fact, your current definition of `Job` provides little that you wouldn't get with just `struct Job { int job_id_, runtime_secs_, next_job_id_; };`

Comment: yea i originally didn't have those, added as I tried to figure out what's wrong. @Someprogrammerdude yea i tried using gdb. The values all seem valid to me.

Comment: `chain = &chains.back();` and `chain_map[job.next_job_id_] = chain;` looks like the problem to me. I expect you will have a dangling pointer in the map after the chains vector changes size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're holding on to an invalid pointer.

```
Chain* chain;
if (res == chain_map.end())
{
    chains.emplace_back();
    chain = &chains.back();
} else
{
    chain = res->second;
}
```

Calling `emplace_back()` may cause the entire `vector` data to be reallocated and its contents moved to the new memory location. When that happens, the pointer(s) you stored in the `chain_map` variable become invalid.

Maybe consider using a `list` instead, as it doesn't have to hold a contiguous block of memory, and you can hold onto references between insertions.

Otherwise, just avoid using raw pointers like that. As you can see, they can be tricky unless you really understand what's going on.

Comment: that was it! Changing the vector of chains to a list solved the issue. Thank you! If I had used a smart pointer would that have at least led to a more informative error?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that holding iterators has the same problem as raw pointers - they are invalidated by `emplace_back()`.

Answer (score 3):

In `main()`, you have declared `std::vector<Chain> chains;` which has size 0 and 0 capacity.

The first time you parse a line and don't find it in your map, and thus `emplace_back()` a new chain in `chains`, and store a pointer to this new chain in the map. No problem so far.

The problem is the next time you do `chains.emplace_back()`, the vector has no more capacity and needs to get more space. It is likely that there is no space available adjacent to its current memory, and thus the vector needs to reallocate a bigger space, moving all its stored `Chain`'s. Now they live at a new memory address. But you still have a pointer to the old chain stored in the map.

The next time you parse a line, with a `job_id` previously seen, you will invoke *undefined behavior* by accessing an invalid chain and potentially segfault.

This problem always happens with `std::vector`, when `push_back`-ing or `emplace_back`-ing items. All iterators into the vector (and also pointers to elements) which have existed before, might not be valid anymore, because of the possible relocation of `std::vector`'s memory.

To prevent this, you could construct `chains` in `main()` with a size for which you know there will not be more jobs. Say, there are a maximum of `n` jobs, so construct `chains` and reserve space for `n` chain's

```
std::vector<Chain> chains;
chains.reserve(n);
```

this gives you a vector with `n` capacity.

Alternatively, instead of storing pointers to chains in the map, you could store indices to the chains.

Comment: or use a use `std::list<Chain>` instead of  `std::vector<Chain>` as Terence mentioned, because a list does not need to reallocate when adding elements, because its storage is not contiguous anyways.

Comment: "*Say, there are a maximum of `n` jobs, so construct chains as `std::vector<Chain> chains(n);`, this gives you a vector with `n` capacity*" - and a size of `n`, too. You would be pre-filling the `chains` with `n` objects up front. That may or may not be desirable, depending on the situation. You are probably thinking of `reserve()` instead, eg: `std::vector<Chain> chains; chains.reserve(n);` That will reserve `n` capacity without creating `n` objects right away. Then you can `[push|emplace]_back()` all you want, as long as you don't exceeed the reserved capacity.

Comment: yes absolutely, corrected the answer